# SharePoint 2010: Application Server Administration Service Timer Job

Tags: 2010, search, administration, timer-jobs, performance

One of our customers has a large SharePoint 2010 farm which was having problems with 100% CPU usage for a large part of every minute (15 seconds) when the Application Server Administration Service Timer Job was being run.  The default schedule for the job is every minute, and although the web front ends were load balanced, the entire farm performed poorly due to such a large amount of time for each server being at 100% CPU.  We have resolved the issue by changing the timer job to run every 10 minutes, but are concerned this may have side effects.

What side effects might we experience if the Application Server Administration Service Timer Job only runs every 10 minutes, instead of the default of 1 minute?

Thank you!

Comment: Question is more like: What does this timer job precisely do?

Comment: I agree, although further analysis of what the job does as it relates to this particular environment is also appreciated.